# What does "count=(count && count.length || 0);" do?

Tags: javascript

Below is a simple snippet:

```
pass="Hello";
count=pass.match(/[A-Z]/g);
count=(count && count.length || 0);
alert(count); //1
```

I just didn't get how the third line works, `count=(count && count.length || 0);`. What is the logic behind? Thanks!

Comment: condition if true (1) else false (0)

Comment: If there is a count variable, and it has length, use it, otherwise use zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's short for:

```
if (count) {
  count = count.length;
} else {
  count = 0;
}
```

Comment: count=(count && count.length);  means ?

Comment: @SHIN `if (count) { count = count.length }`

Comment: are you sure ? this one  if (count) { count = count.length } or if (count) { count = count.length;} else { count = 0;} itslef

Comment: @SHIN actually, `if (count) { count = count.length } else { count = count }` (`String.match()` returns either an array of matches, or `null` where there weren't any matches)

Comment: got it . but count=(count && count.length || 0); and count=(count && count.length); are same right ?

Answer (score 3):

It is basically equivalent to

```
count = (count)? count.length : 0;
```

or more explicitly

```
if (count)
  count = count.length;
else
  count = 0;
```

Comment: Or `count = (count || []).length` ;)

Comment: @robertklep this is not an obfuscation contest ! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want it written in *English*, it means

If `count` is *truthy*, get `count.length` and then if `count.length` is *falsy*, get `0`. If `count` was *falsy*, get `0`. Set `count` equal to what we got.

You can think of being *truthy* like this (and *falsy* being the inverse)

```
function isTruthy(x) {
    if (x) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is probably the most usefull function ever ;p

Comment: @Drax That `isTruthy` function is to convey the concept if the reader hasn't encountered the terms _truthy_ and _falsy_ before, not something you'd expect to see in practical code.

Comment: understood that, just teasing :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically,  `a=(a && b || c);` is short for

```
if (a)
  a=b
else
  a=c
```

I agreed as I have tested with a in which a in {-1,0,null,1}. What made me confused at first was I thought logical operation would always return true/false or 1/0 value. But now I learnt something new. Thanks all!